# Fonts only display correctly in Incognito Mode

Tags: css, html, fonts, incognito-mode

I'm using a couple of custom fonts in my site, one from google fonts and another that I uploaded along side the index.html. All properly declared in the css file.
When I preview the site throught the HTML Editor (Sublime Text 3) it shows just fine with all the custom fonts in place, but once I upload it to the server and acess the site through the internet all the fonts change to arial, I believe. This also happens in Internet Explorer. I looked the CSS file and its all good. The fonts are declared in the right elements and there is no overwrite.
Now the wierd part is that when I open the site in Inconito Mode from Chrome, the fonts load just fine. Which makes me think that there is no problem with the css. When I inspect the element thought the browser it shows as crossed out.
Have no idea what is causing this, anyone have ever seen something like this?

Comment: Once I used "Open Sans" in my CSS font-family, but actually added "Open Sans Condensed" font... ...for a bit, it worked in incognito (private browsing) mode (probably because of the same name begining?), but not in normal mode. After restarting the browser it stopped working completely and I discovered the issue cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, not only with google fonts but also with fonts I made myself and are uploaded to the same server; In my case it was because I installed the chrome app disable web fonts (without knowing that I did that), and this app isn't working in incognito mode.

Comment: I feel very, very stupid right now! Guess I had that same extention as well. Funny thing is, I don't remember installing it in the first place. 
Well, at least I hope I learned the leason to keep track of all those apps and extentions I install on chrome!
Although the problem persist in IE. But IE is a lost cause all together so...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to clear the cache of your browser. If your using google font, i guess your reference is made to the google site. Make sure the server can access the google site.

I have already experienced a delay for the font to load because of the external reference.

Hope this help.